# Get post with infinite scroll not working in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

Js code:-
im having trouble to load the post when i added following js code. i have get and post method defined in view but none of works.

```
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
handler: function(direction) {

},
offset: 'bottom-in-view',

onBeforePageLoad: function () {
    $('.spinner-border').show();
},
onAfterPageLoad: function () {
    $('.spinner-border').hide();
}
```

});

my view function :-

```
class IndexView(ListView):
model = Posts
paginate_by = 4
context_object_name = 'content'
template_name = 'dashboard.html'
form = PostsForm

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_form = self.form()
    return render( request, self.template_name, { 'post_form' : post_form } )

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_form = self.form( request.POST, request.FILES )
    if post_form.is_valid():
        current_user = User.objects.get( id = request.user.id )
        post_title = request.POST.get( 'title', False )
        post_content = request.POST.get( 'content', False )
        post_tags = request.POST.get( 'tags', False )
        post_source = request.POST.get( 'source', False )
        post_form = Posts( title = post_title, slug = slugify( post_title ), user = current_user,  content = post_content, tags = post_tags, source = post_source )
        post_form.save()
        messages.success( request, 'Visit My Post section to find out how it looks')
        return redirect( 'micro__blog:dashboard' )
    else:
        messages.error( request, "Error while saving, try again." )
    return render( request, self.template_name, { 'post_form' : post_form } )
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I'm experiencing the same issue and would rather not repeat the question. I get the spinning icon just spinning but new posts don't display.

Comment: yup, check out this link, should be helpfull    https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html